# Jquery mobile ajax calls not working in blackberry

Tags: jquery, blackberry, cordova

my app is working fine on Android, but there is still one problem which i am unable to figureout, in blackberry all phonegap related functions are working now but my ajax calls (which calls a a file on webserver for some data feeds) are not working at all on blackberry, it shows loading state but never loads anything and the same feature works beautifully on android

any help ?

thank you

Comment: Can you post some of your code so we can see the way you're making the call?